# how do new browsers deal with Sub-Pixel Problems in CSS?

Tags: css

There is this old article by [John Resig from 2008](https://johnresig.com/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/) in which he describes how browsers of old dealt with problems of sub-pixel rendering.
For example if you have 4 floated divs, each with a width of 25%, contained within a parent div of width 50px, how wide are each of the divs?
Since mathematically each of those divs is 12.5px wide and there is no such thing as 0.5 pixel some browsers round it down to 12px some round it up to 13px or mixture of both.

Does anybody knows how today, 13 years after, modern browsers deal with this problem?

Comment: Which "Modern browsers" are you talking about? Detailing the specifications of how even Chrome deals with this on all of the platforms it supports would take more space than an answer has.

Comment: that's not an answer

Comment: I agree. It's a comment. That's why I entered it in the comment field, not the Answer box. If you read the comment, it's also why I voted to close the question, since it is too broad to be answered accurately and fully on Stack Overflow.

Comment: it took Resig one paragraph to explain it, somehow you need PhD thesis

Answer (score 0):

It's highly dependent on the hardware, the browser and the operating system. Just today I was fixing a reported issue that a line looks thicker than the exact same line on different menu item reported by a customer using a Windows machine. On my Mac with my retina screen it still looks perfect. The reason was the thickness. It was `0.5px` and it was enough for people to notice it.

I also encountered bugs where flex items were not fitting in a row because of errors in subpixels rounding. It's 2021 and yes, it is still not safe to use it. Ignore at all cost, round it or ceil it but never use a fraction of a pixel in CSS.